# No puedo agregar items a un RecyclerView, kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, adapter

Descargue un codigo que me resulto entendible de incorporar a mi proyecto dado que estoy en el proceso de aprendizaje del ide y el lenguaje. El ejemplo planteado consta de un adaptador para el RecyclerView, pudiendose agregar, ordenar y eliminar items. Dejo por aqui el link del proyecto que yo descargue: https://github.com/deloss/ToDoApp .El autor es Santiago de los Santos.

El problema es que solo puedo agregar un item extra al listado, quedando el array de 10 item por defecto que lo hace en el onCreate y este nuevo, y al querer agregar otro item este, reemplaza al primero, osea solo puedo agregar un item. Existe la funcion dentro del adapter para agregar items, lo hace desde el floatingbutton que te lleva a un segundo activity mediante startActivityForResult, donde colocas el dato del nuevo item, retornando el dato con setResult y putExtra, donde el activityMain lo espera con onActivityResult. Intente un monton de cosas, puedo decirles que con otro boton y el codigo que esta dentro de onActivityResult puedo agregar items programaticamente, pero no desde el segundo activity, les invito a probar el codigo, inclusive le escribi al autor del codigo pero no he recibido respuesta, espero que ustedes puedan ayudarme y seguir aprendiendo. Debajo dejare los codigos correspondientes. Muchas gracias.

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

val AGREGAR_TAREA_CODE = 1

lateinit var tareaAdapter : TareaAdapter
lateinit var mainLayout : ConstraintLayout


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    mainLayout = activity_content
    val tareas = ArrayList<Tarea>()
    for(i in 0..10) {
        tareas.add(Tarea(i.toString(), false))
    }
    tareaAdapter = TareaAdapter(tareas)
    recycler_view.adapter = tareaAdapter
    recycler_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recycler_view.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL))

    agregar_tarea.setOnClickListener {
        startActivityForResult(Intent(this, AgregarTareaActivity::class.java), AGREGAR_TAREA_CODE)
    }

    val itemTouchHelperCallback = object : ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {
        override fun getMovementFlags(
            recyclerView: RecyclerView,
            viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        ): Int {
            return makeMovementFlags(ItemTouchHelper.UP.or(ItemTouchHelper.DOWN), ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT)
        }

        override fun onMove(
            recyclerView: RecyclerView,
            viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        ): Boolean {
            val posicionInicial = viewHolder.adapterPosition
            val posicionFinal = target.adapterPosition
            tareaAdapter.cambiarPosicionItem(posicionInicial, posicionFinal)
            return true
        }

        override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
            val posicion = viewHolder.adapterPosition
            val tarea = tareaAdapter.getTarea(posicion)
            tareaAdapter.eliminarTarea(posicion)
            val snackbar = Snackbar.make(mainLayout, "Eliminaste una tarea", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            snackbar.setAction("Deshacer") {
                tareaAdapter.restaurarTarea(posicion, tarea)
            }
            snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.YELLOW)
            snackbar.show()
        }

    }

    val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback)
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recycler_view)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if(requestCode == AGREGAR_TAREA_CODE) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val tareaDescripcion = data!!.extras!!["tarea"] as String
            val tareaCreada = Tarea(tareaDescripcion, false)
            tareaAdapter.agregarTarea(tareaCreada)
        }
    }
}
```

Adaptador:

```
class TareaAdapter(private var tareas: ArrayList<Tarea> = ArrayList()) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TareaAdapter.TareaViewHolder>() {

class TareaViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)

fun agregarTarea(tarea: Tarea) {
    tareas.add(tarea)
    notifyItemInserted(itemCount)
}

fun setTareas(tareas : ArrayList<Tarea>) {
    this.tareas = tareas
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

fun getTarea(posicion: Int) : Tarea {
    return tareas[posicion]
}

fun eliminarTarea(posicion: Int) {
    tareas.removeAt(posicion)
    notifyItemRemoved(posicion)
}

fun restaurarTarea(posicion: Int, tarea: Tarea) {
    tareas.add(posicion, tarea)
    notifyItemInserted(posicion)
}

fun cambiarPosicionItem(posicionInicial: Int, posicionFinal: Int) {
    val tarea = tareas[posicionInicial]
    tareas.removeAt(posicionInicial)
    tareas.add(posicionFinal, tarea)
    notifyItemMoved(posicionInicial, posicionFinal)
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TareaViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.tarea_item, parent, false)
    return TareaViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return tareas.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TareaViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.itemView.nombre.text = tareas[position].nombre
    holder.itemView.tarea_terminada.isChecked = tareas[position].terminada
    if(holder.itemView.tarea_terminada.isChecked)
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(holder.itemView.context, R.color.tarea_terminada))
    else
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(holder.itemView.context, R.color.tarea_no_terminada))
    holder.itemView.tarea_terminada.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
        if(isChecked)
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(holder.itemView.context, R.color.tarea_terminada))
        else
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(holder.itemView.context, R.color.tarea_no_terminada))
    }
}

}
```

Data Class:

```
data class Tarea(
val nombre: String,
val terminada: Boolean
)
```

Segundo activity, que es donde se carga el nuevo item:

```
class AgregarTareaActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_agregar_tarea)

    crear_tarea.setOnClickListener {
        val tareaDescripcion = tarea.text.toString()
        if(tareaDescripcion.isEmpty())
            Toast.makeText(this, "Debes ingresar una tarea", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        else {
            val intent = Intent()
            intent.putExtra("tarea", tareaDescripcion)
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
            finish()
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: No entiendo cuál es la pregunta... ¿Quieres añadir items desde la sub activity sin emplear el setResult?

Comment: Hola! Lo que quieres hacer es agregar ítems a tu Adapter que esta en Main Activity desde AgregarTareaActivity sin utilizar el método onActivityResult?

Comment: lo que quiero es agregar todos los items que yo quiera, pero puedo solo agregar uno, ya que el posterior vendria a ser el 2do item reemplaza al 1er item, osea en definitiva solo puedo agregar un item, me explico?, algo falla, presupongo qpuede ser onactivityresult